# "Expected specifier-quantifier-list before b2Body" error in XCode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to derive class from CCSprite to store the sprites reference to its corresponding b2Body, but I've get the following errors (comments in Code)

BoxSprite.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface BoxSprite : CCSprite {
    b2Body* bod; // Expected specifier-quantifier-list before b2Body
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) b2Body* bod; // Expected specifier-quantifier-list before b2Body

@end // Property 'bod' with 'retain' attribute must be of object type
```

BoxSprite.m

```
#import "BoxSprite.h"

@implementation BoxSprite

@synthesize bod; // No declaration of property 'bod' found in the interface

- (void) dealloc
{
    [bod release]; // 'bod' undeclared
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I was hoping to create the sprite and assign the body with:

```
BoxSprite *sprite = [BoxSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batch rect:CGRectMake(32 * idx,32 * idy,32,32)];
...
sprite->bod = body; // Instance variable 'bod' is declared protected
```

Then access the b2Body by:

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[BoxSprite class]]) {
    BoxSprite *spr = (BoxSprite*)node;
    b2Body *body = spr->bod; // Instance variable 'bod' is declared protected
    ...
}
```

Comment: Its not finding the definition for `b2Body` class, where is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) b2Body* bod;
```

use

```
@property (assign) b2Body *bod;
```

since you're not passing an objective-c object.
The @synthesize directive will work too so you do not need to create your own getter and setter methods unless you want to do something else at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

b2Body is a C++ object, and so I have to make my own getters and setters, and rename BoxSprite.m to a .mm file.

BoxSprite.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface BoxSprite : CCSprite {
    b2Body* bod;
}

-(b2Body*) getBod;
-(void) setBod:(b2Body *)b;

@end
```

BoxSprite.mm

```
#import "BoxSprite.h"

@implementation BoxSprite

-(b2Body*) getBod {
    return bod;
}

-(void) setBod:(b2Body *)b {
    bod = b;
}

@end
```

Create:

```
BoxSprite *sprite = [BoxSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batch rect:CGRectMake(32 * idx,32 * idy,32,32)];
...
[sprite setBod:body];
```

Access:

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[BoxSprite class]]) {
    BoxSprite *spr = (BoxSprite*)node;
    b2Body *body = [spr getBod];
    ...
}
```